# Reorder divs in javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, dom

lets say I have html:

```
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
```

how would I in javascript and not jquery reorder these divs to:

```
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
```

Comment: what order... any random or specific.

Comment: I want to move div 3 to between div 1 and 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` and the `order` css (I had to add a letter before the number for your id as SO didn't seem to like it for the css)

```css
.container {display:flex; flex-direction:column}
#s1 {order:1;}
#s2 {order:3;}
#s3 {order:2;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="s1">1</div>
  <div id="s2">2</div>
  <div id="s3">3</div>
</div>
```

[More information about order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

[More information about flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**Update**

Sorry read the question wrong - thought you wanted to do it without js

```js
var div = document.getElementById('3')

div.parentNode.insertBefore(div, document.getElementById('2'))
```

```html
      <div id="1">1</div>
      <div id="2">2</div>
      <div id="3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by the duplicate questions are incorrect because they make the assumption that the elements are next to each other. But even in this simple example, there is a text node containing white-space between the elements.

Given that the two elements are not nested, you can use this to swap two elements:

```
function swapElements (first, second) {
    var tmpNode = document.createElement('div');
    tmpNode.setAttribute('id', '_tmp');

    var firstParent = first.parentNode;
    firstParent.insertBefore(tmpNode, first);
    second.parentNode.insertBefore(second, first);
    firstParent.insertBefore(second, tmpNode);
    firstParent.removeChild(tmpNode);
}
```

Use it like:

```
var first = document.querySelector('#1');
var second = document.querySelector('#2');
swapElements(first, second);
```

Comment: what is the use of tmpNode in the process? is it ok to just remove that part in the function?